# Catching event in Laravel with Livewire and Echo

Tags: php, laravel, events, pusher, laravel-livewire

I made a laravel chat test with Laravel, Livewire, Laravel echo package and pusher.

I have a main room with a list of different room and the users can move to each room for chating with others. In each different room, i have the list of the users connected.

Everything going well.

So, now, I would like to show in main room the same list of users and if, one of them move to a others room, showing that the user still connected and the name of the room where he moved.

For that, I created a event "userConnected" like that :

```
class userConnected implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $room;
    public $user;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Room $room, $user)
    {
        $this->room = $room;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('rooms');
    }
}
```

Then, when a user joining a room, I dispatch the event :

```
public function joining($user)
    {
        if(! in_array($this->users, $user)) {
            
            $this->users[] = $user;
            // envoyer evenement : room
            $this->emit('newConnection');
            

            broadcast(new userConnected($this->room, $user))->toOthers();
        }
    }
```

After that, in my livewire rooms controller, I listen the event like that :

```
protected function getListeners() 
    {
        return [
            "echo-presence:rooms,here" =>'here',
            "echo-presence:rooms,joining" =>'joining',
            "echo-presence:rooms,leaving" =>'leaving',
            'newConnection' => 'newConnection',
            "echo-private:rooms,userConnected" => 'newConnection',

        ];
    }
```

And my method :

```
public function newConnection() 
    {
        $this->stillConnected = true;
    }
```

And of course, my channels.php file :

```
Broadcast::channel('connected', function ($users) {
    return $users;
});
```

And my questions is : now, how catching the event in my room main livewire controller ?

Because they are nothing happens...

My variable :

```
$stillConnected
```

stay at false...
Maybe I'm not doing it right...

If someone have a idea...

Comment: Check your channel is rooms not connected. That should fix that error